# Is there a way to use defaultLayout and a source (conduit) in Yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod, conduit

I'm trying to optimise an Yesod application so that it runs in constant space.
For example, I'm reading a DB table and display it as an HTML table. I should be able to start sending the first row before having finished processing the full table. I understand I can do that using `selectSource`(to read the DB) and `responseSource` or `responseSourceDB` but I how can wrap it in the default layout using `defaultLayout` ?

At the moment I have to consume the full source to generate a list and the Html in one go. For example let say I have (might not compiles)

```
   data User = {name :: Text, email :: Text } deriving ...

   userSource = selectSource [] [Asc UserName]
   userToTR user = [whamlet|
             <tr>
                  <td>#{user name}
                  <td>#{user email}


   getUsers :: Handler Html
   getUsers = do
      rows <- runConduit $ userSource =$= mapC userToTR =$= sinkList
      table = [whamlet|
         <table>
           <tr>
             <th>Name
             <th>Email
           ^{mconcat rows}

       defaultLayout table
```

How I can transform this to stream the rows nicely ?
(This is only a made up example to explain the problem, the real problem is much more complicated).

Comment: Maybe this can be of any help? https://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2013/03/simpler-streaming-responses

Comment: Nope, as it doesn't use `defaultLayout` in the streamed response. However, this page https://www.yesodweb.com/book/sql-joins explicitly says that " We also lose the ability to use defaultLayout". :-(